# How to invoke module-path in a portable manner across Windows and *nix platforms?

Tags: java, module-path

[Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/basic-packaging.html#GUID-1E2A4F61-1390-4FC3-955B-BD69A16FCA2C) states that:

> module-path is the path to either a directory of modules or to a modular JAR file. The path can be absolute or relative to the current directory. For more than one path, separate the paths with a colon (:) on Linux and macOS or a semi-colon (;) on Windows, or use multiple instances of the --module-path option.

I tried using multiple instances of the `--module-path` option in the hopes of using the same command-line across all platforms, but no luck. It seems that the last `--module-path` option overwrites the previous values.

Is this a bug? Is there a portable workaround I can use?

Comment: In the context of `jlink`, [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8165735) states explicitly “*If --module-path is specified multiple times then it should be last one wins.*” I suppose, all tools should behave consistently, so the documentation page is wrong.